# how to create a authentication rule if i use seperate login for two folders say admin folder and vendor folder

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, web-config

I have the following directory structure in my asp.net webdirectory !
[image]

i want when any body access anypage inside my admin folder then it auto redirect to login page of admin folder until they login ... using login page ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this in Configureation section of the web.config

```
<location path="Admin">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?"/>
            <allow roles="Super Admin"/>//you can allow to specific roles to access folder
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>

<authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms name="SignIn" loginUrl="~/login.aspx" defaultUrl="~/Default.aspx"/>
    </authentication>
```

Comment: how to do that ..if i use ... seperate login for two folders ... say admin folder and vendor folder